# Xamarin forms, OSM file, system IO File not found exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, file-handling

Hi I am having trouble with some file handling in Xamarin forms. Each time I run my code I keep getting the systemIO FileNotfound exception. The code I am using is below. The stuff about routerDB is part of a pathfinding NuGet package I am using called Itinero. Before my code can even reach the create routerDb.LoadOsmData line it keeps getting stuck at line 4 and returning the error: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file "/Date\wales-latest.osm.pbf"'

Here is the the absolute path of that file "wales-latest.osm.pbf" in Xamarin forms.

C:\USW Pathfinder\USW Pathfinder\USW Pathfinder\bin\Debug\Date

I was so frustrated this did not work that I created another program but this time a windows forms one and I entered the same code as below and it worked first time flawlessly and created me the file wales.router.db as I expected.

Here is the absolute path of that file "wales-latest.osm.pbf" in Windows forms.

C:\Users\MYNAME\Desktop\Pathfinder\Pathfinder\bin\Debug\Date

I have also tried simpler file handling code in Xamarin forms to see if I can reach any file as shown in the second code block and I am always met with file not found.

Please can anyone suggest why this would be?

```
 private void LoadButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        var routerDb = new RouterDb();
        using (var stream = new FileInfo(@"Date\wales-latest.osm.pbf").OpenRead())
        {
            // create the network for cars.
            routerDb.LoadOsmData(stream, Vehicle.Car);
        }

        // write the routerdb to disk.
        using (var stream = new FileInfo(@"wales.routerdb").Open(FileMode.Create))
        {
            routerDb.Serialize(stream);
        };
    }
```

```
public void ReadButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              File.ReadAllText(@"Date\wales-latest.osm.pbf");

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c:\` is a folder on **YOUR PC**.  Xamarin is running on a mobile device (or emulator) and at runtime it does not have access to your PC's filesystem.  If you want to include a file as part of your application, you need to include as part of your project so that it is deployed with your app

Xamarin docs have entire writeup on [working with files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows)

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely what the issue was, now I am able to move on to the next part of my newbie adventure in trying to figure out how to include it as part of my project.